# How to show last data entry of tables are not directly related

Tags: sql-server

So I've read the posts about retrieving the last entry added to a table, but I can't get it to work for me since my query is slightly more complex.
I'm using SQL server and I'm a beginner with SQL queries.

I need to make a list with patients of a certain practice and their last consult. For this I have three tables:

- Patients.patients (patient data, also contains practice id)
- Consults.consults (contains no patient data!)
- Consults.Patients (links consult is to patient id)

This is what I have got so far:

```
SELECT   p.DebtorNumber
         ,p.ContactDetails_LastName
         ,c.Startdate
         ,c.ConsultNumber

FROM Patients.patients as p

JOIN consults.patients as pc on p.id=pc.Patient_Id
JOIN consults.Consults as c on pc.Parent_Id=c.id

WHERE p.HealthCare_Id=90
```

---

I use regular JOINS because I'm only interested in patients that have consults. This query retrieves all the consults of the patients in practice id 90, but I only need the most recent one.

As I have read other posts about this issue, I know that I should use a subquery and a TOP 1. But in the other examples the table they pulled the TOP 1 from was directly related to the main table.

I think I need to add to my WHERE, but this sure doesn't work:

```
and c.id in (select top 1 c.id where pc.Patient_Id=p.id order by start DESC)
```

How do I only get the last consult for each patient? This would be the consult with the highest Consults.Consults.Startdate.

Thanks in advance guys, I've gotten in over my head here.

Comment: Add sample and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) for this.  EG

```
with q as
(
    SELECT   p.DebtorNumber
             ,p.ContactDetails_LastName
             ,c.Startdate
             ,c.ConsultNumber
             ,row_number() over (partition by p.id order p c.start desc) rn

    FROM Patients.patients as p

    JOIN consults.patients as pc on p.id=pc.Patient_Id
    JOIN consults.Consults as c on pc.Parent_Id=c.id

    WHERE p.HealthCare_Id=90
)
SELECT   p.DebtorNumber
        ,p.ContactDetails_LastName
        ,c.Startdate
        ,c.ConsultNumber
FROM q
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will read up on using row_number and partition by.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query as below:

```
SELECT top (1) with ties  
          p.DebtorNumber
         ,p.ContactDetails_LastName
         ,c.Startdate
         ,c.ConsultNumber

FROM Patients.patients as p

JOIN consults.patients as pc on p.id=pc.Patient_Id
JOIN consults.Consults as c on pc.Parent_Id=c.id

WHERE p.HealthCare_Id=90
Order by row_number() over (partition by p.id order by c.start desc)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never used a select with ties, or partition before, but that partition was exactly what I needed to get the result per patient. Perfect!